# How to fit long equations in table

Tags: tables, math-mode, tabularx

I have set of benchmark problems for numerical optimization I'd like to compile in a table.
The table consists of function name, function definition, search range and the theoretical global optimum. The problem is the equations don't fit in the table. I'm using tabularx as shown in the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=30mm,
    right=25mm,
    top=30mm,
    bottom=30mm,
    asymmetric
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|X|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Definition} & \textbf{Search range} & \textbf{Global optimum}\\
        \hline
        Sphere & $f_1(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{D} x_i^2$ & $[-5.12, 5.12]^D$ & $f_1(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \hline
        Rosenbrock & $f_2(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{D-1} (100 (x_{i+1} - x_i^2)^2 + (x_i - 1)^2) $ & $[-2.048, 2.048]^D$ & $f_2(\vec{1}) = 0$\\
        \hline
        Rastrigin & $f_3(\vec{x}) = 10D + \sum_{i=1}^D \left(x_i^2 -10\cos(2\pi x_i)\right) $ & $[-5.12, 5.12]^D$ & $f_3(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \hline
        Griewank & $f_4(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^D \frac{x_i^2}{4000} - \prod_{i=1}^D \cos(\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{i}}) + 1 $ & $[-600, 600]^D$ & $f_4(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \hline
        Ackley & $f_5(\vec{x}) = -a\;\exp\left(-b \sqrt{\frac{1}{D} \sum_{i=1}^D x_i^2}\right) - \exp\left(\frac{1}{D} \sum_{i=1}^D \cos(c\;x_i)\right) + a + \exp(1) $& $[-32.768, 32.768]^D$ & $f_5(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \hline
        Schwefel & $f_6(\vec{x}) = 418.9829d - \sum_{i=1}^{D} x_i \sin(\sqrt{\lvert x_i \rvert}) $ & $[-500, 500]^D$ & $f_6(\vec{420.9687}) = 0$\\
        \hline
        Alpine & $f_7(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{D} \lvert x_i \sin(x_i)+0.1x_i \rvert $ & $[-10, 10]^D$ & $f_7(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \hline
        Whitley & $f_8(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^D \sum_{j=1}^D \left(\frac{(100(x_i^2-x_j)^2 + (1-x_j)^2)^2}{4000} - \cos(100(x_i^2-x_j)^2 + (1-x_j)^2)+1\right) $ & $[-10, 10]^D$ & $f_8(\vec{1}) = 0$\\
        \hline
        Csendes & $f_9(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^D x_i^6\left( 2 + \sin \frac{1}{x_i}\right) $ & $[-1, 1]^D$ & $f_9(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \hline
        Dixon Price & $f_{10}(\vec{x}) = (x_1 - 1)^2 + \sum_{i = 2}^D i (2x_i^2 - x_{i - 1})^2 $ & $[-10, 10]^D$ & $f_{10}(x^*) = 0 \; x_i = 2^{-\frac{2^i - 2}{2^i}} $\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It produces this mess:
[image]

Is there a way to get all the math to fit in its cells and make this table look somewhat presentable? I've been losing my mind over this for the past few hours.
. I've also tried putting it in landscape using the lscape package and setting the width to 24cm and it still doesn't fit. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: it would help if you provided a working example but are you sure you want a 4-column table, it is never going tio be readable, I'd use the full width of the page for the data you have in column 2

Comment: you are using X columns so forcing all columns to be equal width so allocating as much space for your long definitions as you are for your search range.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the example should be working, and I haven't thought about organizing the data in two separate tables. Great idea, thank you!

Comment: No I mean you had only posted a fragment not a complete document

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could consider a non table layout

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item [sphere] Search range $[-5.12, 5.12]^D$,  Global optimum $f_1(\vec{0}) = 0$
\[f_1(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{D} x_i^2\]
\item[Rosenbrock] Search Range $[-2.048, 2.048]^D$, Global optimum $f_2(\vec{1}) = 0$
\[f_2(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{D-1} (100 (x_{i+1} - x_i^2)^2 + (x_i - 1)^2)\]
\item[Rastrigin] Search Range $[-5.12, 5.12]^D$, Global optimum  $f_3(\vec{0}) = 0$
\[f_3(\vec{x}) = 10D + \sum_{i=1}^D \left(x_i^2 -10\cos(2\pi x_i)\right) \]
\item[Griewank] Search Range $[-600, 600]^D$, Global optimum $f_4(\vec{0}) = 0$
\[ f_4(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^D \frac{x_i^2}{4000} - \prod_{i=1}^D \cos(\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{i}}) + 1 \]
\item[Ackley] Search Range $[-32.768, 32.768]^D$, Global optimum $f_5(\vec{0}) = 0$
\[ f_5(\vec{x}) = -a\;\exp\left(-b \sqrt{\frac{1}{D} \sum_{i=1}^D x_i^2}\right) - \exp\left(\frac{1}{D} \sum_{i=1}^D \cos(c\;x_i)\right) + a + \exp(1)  \]
\item[Schwefel] Search Range $[-500, 500]^D$, Global optimum $f_6(\vec{420.9687}) = 0$
\[ f_6(\vec{x}) = 418.9829d - \sum_{i=1}^{D} x_i \sin(\sqrt{\lvert x_i \rvert})  \]
\item[Alpine] Search Range $[-10, 10]^D$, Global optimum $f_7(\vec{0}) = 0$
\[ f_7(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{D} \lvert x_i \sin(x_i)+0.1x_i \rvert  \]
\item[Whitley] Search Range $[-10, 10]^D$, Global optimum $f_8(\vec{1}) = 0$
\[ f_8(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^D \sum_{j=1}^D \left(\frac{(100(x_i^2-x_j)^2 + (1-x_j)^2)^2}{4000} - \cos(100(x_i^2-x_j)^2 + (1-x_j)^2)+1\right)  \]
\item[Csendes] Search Range $[-1, 1]^D$, Global optimum $f_9(\vec{0}) = 0$
\[ f_9(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^D x_i^6\left( 2 + \sin \frac{1}{x_i}\right) \]
\item[Dixon Price] Search Range $[-10, 10]^D$, Global optimum $f_{10}(x^*) = 0 \; x_i = 2^{-\frac{2^i - 2}{2^i}} $
\[ f_{10}(\vec{x}) = (x_1 - 1)^2 + \sum_{i = 2}^D i (2x_i^2 - x_{i - 1})^2  \]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are some more alternatives:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=30mm,
    right=25mm,
    top=30mm,
    bottom=30mm,
    asymmetric
}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Definition} & \textbf{Search range} & \textbf{Global optimum}\\
        \hline
        Sphere & $f_1(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{D} x_i^2$ & $[-5.12, 5.12]^D$ & $f_1(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \hline
        Rosenbrock & $f_2(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{D-1} (100 (x_{i+1} - x_i^2)^2 + (x_i - 1)^2) $ & $[-2.048, 2.048]^D$ & $f_2(\vec{1}) = 0$\\
        \hline
        Rastrigin & $f_3(\vec{x}) = 10D + \sum_{i=1}^D \left(x_i^2 -10\cos(2\pi x_i)\right) $ & $[-5.12, 5.12]^D$ & $f_3(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \hline
        Griewank & $f_4(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^D \frac{x_i^2}{4000} - \prod_{i=1}^D \cos(\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{i}}) + 1 $ & $[-600, 600]^D$ & $f_4(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \hline
        Ackley & $f_5(\vec{x}) = -a\;\exp\left(-b \sqrt{\frac{1}{D} \sum_{i=1}^D x_i^2}\right) - \exp\left(\frac{1}{D} \sum_{i=1}^D \cos(c\;x_i)\right) + a + \exp(1) $& $[-32.768, 32.768]^D$ & $f_5(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \hline
        Schwefel & $f_6(\vec{x}) = 418.9829d - \sum_{i=1}^{D} x_i \sin(\sqrt{\lvert x_i \rvert}) $ & $[-500, 500]^D$ & $f_6(\vec{420.9687}) = 0$\\
        \hline
        Alpine & $f_7(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{D} \lvert x_i \sin(x_i)+0.1x_i \rvert $ & $[-10, 10]^D$ & $f_7(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \hline
        Whitley & $f_8(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^D \sum_{j=1}^D \left(\frac{(100(x_i^2-x_j)^2 + (1-x_j)^2)^2}{4000} - \cos(100(x_i^2-x_j)^2 + (1-x_j)^2)+1\right) $ & $[-10, 10]^D$ & $f_8(\vec{1}) = 0$\\
        \hline
        Csendes & $f_9(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^D x_i^6\left( 2 + \sin \frac{1}{x_i}\right) $ & $[-1, 1]^D$ & $f_9(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \hline
        Dixon Price & $f_{10}(\vec{x}) = (x_1 - 1)^2 + \sum_{i = 2}^D i (2x_i^2 - x_{i - 1})^2 $ & $[-10, 10]^D$ & $f_{10}(x^*) = 0 \; x_i = 2^{-\frac{2^i - 2}{2^i}} $\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}


\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \toprule
        Name & Definition, Search Range, Global optimum \\
        \midrule
        Sphere & $f_1(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{D} x_i^2$ \\
               & $[-5.12, 5.12]^D$                     \\
               & $f_1(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \addlinespace
        Rosenbrock & $f_2(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{D-1} (100 (x_{i+1} - x_i^2)^2 + (x_i - 1)^2) $ \\
                   & $[-2.048, 2.048]^D$ \\
                   & $f_2(\vec{1}) = 0$\\
        \addlinespace
        Rastrigin & $f_3(\vec{x}) = 10D + \sum_{i=1}^D \left(x_i^2 -10\cos(2\pi x_i)\right) $ \\
                  & $[-5.12, 5.12]^D$ \\
                  & $f_3(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \addlinespace
        Griewank & $f_4(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^D \frac{x_i^2}{4000} - \prod_{i=1}^D \cos(\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{i}}) + 1 $ \\
                 & $[-600, 600]^D$ \\
                 & $f_4(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \addlinespace
        Ackley & $f_5(\vec{x}) = -a\;\exp\left(-b \sqrt{\frac{1}{D} \sum_{i=1}^D x_i^2}\right) - \exp\left(\frac{1}{D} \sum_{i=1}^D \cos(c\;x_i)\right) + a + \exp(1) $ \\
               & $[-32.768, 32.768]^D$ \\
               & $f_5(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \addlinespace
        Schwefel & $f_6(\vec{x}) = 418.9829d - \sum_{i=1}^{D} x_i \sin(\sqrt{\lvert x_i \rvert}) $ \\
                 & $[-500, 500]^D$ \\
                 & $f_6(\vec{420.9687}) = 0$\\
        \addlinespace
        Alpine & $f_7(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{D} \lvert x_i \sin(x_i)+0.1x_i \rvert $ \\
               & $[-10, 10]^D$ \\
               & $f_7(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \addlinespace
        Whitley & $f_8(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^D \sum_{j=1}^D \left(\frac{(100(x_i^2-x_j)^2 + (1-x_j)^2)^2}{4000} - \cos(100(x_i^2-x_j)^2 + (1-x_j)^2)+1\right) $ \\
                & $[-10, 10]^D$ \\
                & $f_8(\vec{1}) = 0$\\
        \addlinespace
        Csendes & $f_9(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^D x_i^6\left( 2 + \sin \frac{1}{x_i}\right) $ \\
                & $[-1, 1]^D$ \\
                & $f_9(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \addlinespace
        Dixon Price & $f_{10}(\vec{x}) = (x_1 - 1)^2 + \sum_{i = 2}^D i (2x_i^2 - x_{i - 1})^2 $ \\
                    & $[-10, 10]^D$ \\
                    & $f_{10}(x^*) = 0 \; x_i = 2^{-\frac{2^i - 2}{2^i}} $\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
\item Sphere
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Definition: $f_1(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{D} x_i^2$ 
  \item Search range: $[-5.12, 5.12]^D$ 
  \item Global optimum: $f_1(\vec{0}) = 0$
  \end{itemize}
\item  Rosenbrock
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Definition: $f_2(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{D-1} (100 (x_{i+1} - x_i^2)^2 + (x_i - 1)^2) $ 
  \item Search range: $[-2.048, 2.048]^D$ 
  \item Global optimum: $f_2(\vec{1}) = 0$
  \end{itemize}
\item  Rastrigin
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Definition: $f_3(\vec{x}) = 10D + \sum_{i=1}^D \left(x_i^2 -10\cos(2\pi x_i)\right) $
  \item Search range: $[-5.12, 5.12]^D$
  \item Global optimum:  $f_3(\vec{0}) = 0$
  \end{itemize}
\item  Griewank
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Definition: $f_4(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^D \frac{x_i^2}{4000} - \prod_{i=1}^D \cos(\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{i}}) + 1 $
  \item Search range: $[-600, 600]^D$
  \item Global optimum: $f_4(\vec{0}) = 0$
  \end{itemize}
\item  Ackley
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Definition: $f_5(\vec{x}) = -a\;\exp\left(-b \sqrt{\frac{1}{D} \sum_{i=1}^D x_i^2}\right) - \exp\left(\frac{1}{D} \sum_{i=1}^D \cos(c\;x_i)\right) + a + \exp(1) $
  \item Search range: $[-32.768, 32.768]^D$
  \item Global optimum: $f_5(\vec{0}) = 0$ 
  \end{itemize}
\item Schwefel
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Definition: $f_6(\vec{x}) = 418.9829d - \sum_{i=1}^{D} x_i \sin(\sqrt{\lvert x_i \rvert}) $
  \item Search range: $[-500, 500]^D$ 
  \item Global optimum: $f_6(\vec{420.9687}) = 0$
  \end{itemize}
\item  Alpine
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Definition: $f_7(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{D} \lvert x_i \sin(x_i)+0.1x_i \rvert $  
  \item Search range: $[-10, 10]^D$
  \item Global optimum: $f_7(\vec{0}) = 0$
  \end{itemize}
\item Whitley
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Definition: $f_8(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^D \sum_{j=1}^D \left(\frac{(100(x_i^2-x_j)^2 + (1-x_j)^2)^2}{4000} - \cos(100(x_i^2-x_j)^2 + (1-x_j)^2)+1\right) $
  \item Search range: $[-10, 10]^D$
  \item Global optimum: $f_8(\vec{1}) = 0$
  \end{itemize}
\item Csendes
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Definition: $f_9(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^D x_i^6\left( 2 + \sin \frac{1}{x_i}\right) $
  \item Search range: $[-1, 1]^D$
  \item Global optimum: $f_9(\vec{0}) = 0$
  \end{itemize}
\item  Dixon Price
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Definition: $f_{10}(\vec{x}) = (x_1 - 1)^2 + \sum_{i = 2}^D i (2x_i^2 - x_{i - 1})^2 $
  \item Search range: $[-10, 10]^D$
  \item Global optimum: $f_{10}(x^*) = 0 \; x_i = 2^{-\frac{2^i - 2}{2^i}} $
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

In form of your table (for exercise, not recommended) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=30mm,
    right=25mm,
    top=30mm,
    bottom=30mm,
    asymmetric
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|c|l|}
        \hline
\thead{Name} & \thead{Definition} & \thead{Search\\ range} & \thead{Global\\ optimum}\\
        \hline
Sphere & $f_1(\vec{x}) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{D} x_i^2$ & $[-5.12, 5.12]^D$ & $f_1(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \hline
Rosenbrock & $f_2(\vec{x}) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{D-1} (100 (x_{i+1} - x_i^2)^2 + (x_i - 1)^2) $ & $[-2.048, 2.048]^D$ & $f_2(\vec{1}) = 0$\\
        \hline
Rastrigin & $f_3(\vec{x}) = 10D + \sum\limits_{i=1}^D \left(x_i^2 -10\cos(2\pi x_i)\right) $ & $[-5.12, 5.12]^D$ & $f_3(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \hline
Griewank & $f_4(\vec{x}) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^D \frac{x_i^2}{4000} - \prod\limits_{i=1}^D \cos(\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{i}}) + 1 $ & $[-600, 600]^D$ & $f_4(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \hline
Ackley & $ \begin{multlined}
            f_5(\vec{x}) = -a\;\exp\left(-b \sqrt{\frac{1}{D} \sum_{i=1}^D x_i^2}\right)\\
            - \exp\left(\frac{1}{D} \sum_{i=1}^D \cos(c\;x_i)\right) + a + \exp(1) 
            \end{multlined}$
                & $[-32.768, 32.768]^D$ 
                    & $f_5(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \hline
Schwefel & $f_6(\vec{x}) = 418.9829d - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{D} x_i \sin(\sqrt{\lvert x_i \rvert}) $ & $[-500, 500]^D$ & $f_6(\vec{420.9687}) = 0$\\
        \hline
Alpine & $f_7(\vec{x}) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{D} \lvert x_i \sin(x_i)+0.1x_i \rvert $ & $[-10, 10]^D$ & $f_7(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \hline
Whitley & $\begin{multlined}[t]
    f_8(\vec{x}) = \\
    \sum_{i=1}^D \sum_{j=1}^D \Bigl(\frac{(100(x_i^2-x_j)^2 + (1-x_j)^2)^2}{4000}\\ 
                    - \cos(100(x_i^2-x_j)^2 + (1-x_j)^2)+1\Bigr)
            \end{multlined}$ 
                & $[-10, 10]^D$              
                    & $f_8(\vec{1}) = 0$\\        
        \hline
Csendes & $f_9(\vec{x}) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^D x_i^6\left( 2 + \sin \frac{1}{x_i}\right) $ & $[-1, 1]^D$ & $f_9(\vec{0}) = 0$\\
        \hline
Dixon Price & $f_{10}(\vec{x}) = (x_1 - 1)^2 + \sum\limits_{i = 2}^D i (2x_i^2 - x_{i - 1})^2 $ 
                & $[-10, 10]^D$ 
                    & \makecell{$f_{10}(x^*) = 0$,\\ 
                                $x_i = 2^{-\frac{2^i - 2}{2^i}} $}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]